# Can't create foreign key using individual columns against multiple-column primary key

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints

I can not find out what is wrong that i am getting the error message:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 56 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'Airplane_type' that match the
>   referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK_*Airplane*_make__68487DD7'. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 56
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Here is that section of the query:

```
CREATE TABLE Airplane_type
(
make VARCHAR NOT NULL,
model VARCHAR NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
business_capacity INT NOT NULL,
economy_capacity INT NOT NULL,
range INT NOT NULL,
weight INT NOT NULL,
length INT NOT NULL,
wingspan INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(make, model)
);

CREATE TABLE Airplane
(
airplane_ID VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
make VARCHAR NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Airplane_type(make),
model VARCHAR NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Airplane_type(model)
);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created the primary key on two columns, shouldn't the foreign key be created on two columns rather than individually? You can't reference the model column in an individual foreign key because there is nothing in the original table that guarantees that model is unique.

```
CREATE TABLE Airplane
(
  airplane_ID VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  make VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Airplane_type FOREIGN KEY (make, model) 
    REFERENCES Airplane_type(make, model)
);
```

Also, why are you using `VARCHAR` without specifying a length? Please read this blog post:

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Despite 15 years+ of sql server I, didn't know you could do that, course they aren't helping me comne up with a reason why you'd want to.

Comment: Another tip for you @Troy. Put names in for your constraints, use some standard naming convention, it's always helped me when the wheels came off.

Answer (score 1):

The column referenced by a foreign key has to be constrained by a primary key or unique index. Since your primary key is the composite of two columns (make, model), the foreign key should also reference that same composite pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Airplane_type
(
airplane_type_id not null Identity(1,1),
make VARCHAR NOT NULL,
model VARCHAR NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
business_capacity INT NOT NULL,
economy_capacity INT NOT NULL,
range INT NOT NULL,
weight INT NOT NULL,
length INT NOT NULL,
wingspan INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_AIRPLANE_TYPE PRIMARY KEY(airplane_type_id),
Constraint UK_Spotted_By_AARON Unique Key (make, model)
);

CREATE TABLE Airplane
(
airplane_ID VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
airplane_type_id int not null CONSTRAINT FK_Airplane_AirPlane_Type 
  Foreign Key References(AirPlane.Airplane_type_id),
Constraint PK_Airplane Primary Key (Airplane_id),
);
```

Using parts of a compound key as a constraint isn't a goer a far as I know, and if you normalise, it's unnecessary. The way you had your schema an airplane with a make and model combination not in your airplane type table was valid.

Comment: How does adding an identity column and removing the key on `make,model` help anything? Now you can have duplicate `make,model` because your only unique constraint is on the meaningless identity value. At the very least you should still have a unique constraint on `make,model` or vice-versa (a foreign key constraint *can* reference a unique constraint in SQL Server, not just a primary key, so you can have both).

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess here and predict you don't sit on the same side of the surrogate versus natural keys debate. I forgot teh unique constraint, give me a minute. Meaningless identity value is the point...

Comment: No I agree about surrogates I just think an IDENTITY is too commonly thrown onto a table serving as the only unique aspect of the table. My answer to the question was based on explaining why the error message was being thrown, not on redesigning the table. In either design, I fail to see the purpose of the second table.

Comment: Also you've indicated the primary key constraint twice in your second table - once unnamed, once named.

Comment: Ah the cookie cutter auto number approach for tables that "don't have a key". Not a big fan of that myself, more of a rectangular array than a Table, that one.

Comment: @Aaron, fixed that as well. Too close to bed time for mestike free posts. :D